# How to plot the output of scipy's k-means clustering with large number of clusters

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, k-means

My data is 2250 x 100. I would like to plot the output, like http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/04/k-means-clustering-with-scipy.html. However, the problem is that all the examples use only a small number of clusters, usually 2 or 3. How would you plot the output of kmeans in scipy if you wanted more clusters, like a 100.

Here's what I got:

```
 #get the centroids
 centroids,_ = kmeans(data,100)
 idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)
 #do some plotting here...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with 10 colors and 10 point types?

Or you could plot each in a 10 x 10 grid of plots. The first would show the relationships better. The second would allow easier inspection of an arbitrary cluster.